# how to get postition of safari toolbar download button in safari app extension

Tags: javascript, swift, safari, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I want to point an arrow to download button of safari toolbar after one downloads my app extension like below
[image]

but the download button seem to change the position when window size is reduced.
[image]

how to handle this?

Comment: This looks fishy to me, may I ask what your intentions are?

Comment: @Unknown there's nothing wrong that I'm trying to do, I'm building a Safari App Extension and giving a direct download link for it , after download I want user to know that it has been downloaded and to install he/she has to click the download button in toolbar.

Comment: I never had to do anything like that, but I don't think that there's a way to find out where the browsers downloads button is at. You could track it, and maybe calculate its position based on your knowledge on when it moves - but that would be quite dirty --> If I was you, I'd just pop a notification saying that the file is being downloaded :/

Comment: @Unknown thanks :)